# return a JSON object from a GET request

Tags: javascript, json, routes

I am using Node and Express to practice writing routes and was given the following exercise. Can anyone help with the response to my GET request?
Given the follow JSON data:

```
{
  "recipes": [
    {
      "name": "scrambledEggs",
      "ingredients": [
        "1 tsp oil",
        "2 eggs",
        "salt"
      ],
      "instructions": [
        "Beat eggs with salt",
        "Heat oil in pan",
        "Add eggs to pan when hot",
        "Gather eggs into curds, remove when cooked",
        "Salt to taste and enjoy"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "garlicPasta",
      "ingredients": [
        "500mL water",
        "100g spaghetti",
        "25mL olive oil",
        "4 cloves garlic",
        "Salt"
      ],
      "instructions": [
        "Heat garlic in olive oil",
        "Boil water in pot",
        "Add pasta to boiling water",
        "Remove pasta from water and mix with garlic olive oil",
        "Salt to taste and enjoy"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "chai",
      "ingredients": [
        "400mL water",
        "100mL milk",
        "5g chai masala",
        "2 tea bags or 20 g loose tea leaves"
      ],
      "instructions": [
        "Heat water until 80 C",
        "Add milk, heat until 80 C",
        "Add tea leaves/tea bags, chai masala; mix and steep for 3-4 minutes",
        "Remove mixture from heat; strain and enjoy"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am supposed to make a GET request and return the following:

```
{
    "recipeNames":
        [
            "scrambledEggs",
            "garlicPasta",
            "chai"
        ]
}
```

This is what I have so far:

```
app.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
  const recipes = data.recipes;
  const recipeNames = {}
  const arr = []
  for(let i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++){
    let recipe = recipes[i]
    let recipeName = recipe.name
 arr.push(recipeName)
      //recipeNames[arr] = [recipeName]

 }

  res.status(200).send(arr)
})
```

which is giving me :

```
{
  [
     "scrambledEggs",
     "garlicPasta",
     "chai"
  ]
}
```

How do I get it in a JSON object with key "recipeNames" and value the array?

Answer (score 1):

```
app.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
  const recipes = data.recipes;
  const recipeNames = recipes.recipeNames.map(r => r.name)

  res.status(200).send({recipeNames})
})
```

Comment: `res.json({ recipeNames })` is shorter

Comment: The `send` and `json` are pretty much the same, the status is for deciding which status code will be returned. For GET requests it is 200 as a default.

Comment: FYI should be `recipes.map()`, not `recipes.recipeNames.map()` (based on OP's `for` loop)

Comment: Strong and solid

Answer (score 0):

You can make it as bellow:

```
app.get('/recipes', (req, res) => {
    const recipes = data.recipes;
    const recipeNames = {}
    const arr = []

    for(let i = 0; i < recipes.length; i++){
        let recipe = recipes[i]
        let recipeName = recipe.name
        arr.push(recipeName)
        //recipeNames[arr] = [recipeName]

    }

    let forSend = {"recipeNames": arr}

    res.status(200).send(forSend)
})
```